# How do I get my page's message through Graph API?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get my page's message and be able to reply them through a Python app.
For now, I am just testing queries on the Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). I am trying to get the messages using *me?fields=saved_message_responses*, as in the screenshot
[image]
But I am getting this unknown error. How am I supposed to query for those messages?

I am using my page access token.

Comment: find documentation for `saved_message_responses`. Maybe it needs more arguments.

Comment: saved_message_responses are only templates that the page can respond with, but it’s not the actual messages your page has received. You want https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/conversations